# Best method to store my data in JS objects when I need to change the key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am building a messaging type of application using React for the frontend and Django backend with MongoDB. I am currently having a design issue based on my lack of knowledge in JavaScript.

The flow of this is that when a user sends a message it gets added to a object that keeps track of it. When it is inserted it is given a temporary ID. At this point it is in the "pending" stage. It is then sent to the backend where it will be assigned a real ID and it will be returned in the response. The issue here is updating the temporary ID with the new ID since it is used as the key.

The way my data is structured currently allows me to access messages in O(1). Also since the messages are inserted when sent, it keeps it in a order of oldest -> newest.

A few of the ideas I had for fixing this issue are:

1. I can loop through the messages adding them into a new message. When I find the message that has the temp ID I just insert it into the new object with the real ID. The only issue is this would have to loop through every time a new message is sent since they all start with a temp ID.
2. I can store all the message objects in an array and add a timestamp to each message object. Then when I get the real ID I can just delete the temp ID object and insert the real ID message object. The order would not matter as I would then sort based on message object timestamp.
3. Similar to #2 but instead of all messages in a single array each client would have its own array. This would cut down on filtering through ALL messages to filtering the messages that apply to the client.

Which would be the best option for this type of issue I have or what issues am I going to run into? Keep in mind I would like this to be flexible so that in the future if I need to add onto it I can without a full restructure. And since this is a React app I have to keep rendering in mind.

14, 15, and 18 are the client IDs. Everything under them belong to that client. Inside of each is the message ID and then the data to that message.

Here is an example of my data:

```
let messages = {
    '14': {
        '20': {msg: '', msg_status: '', msg_error: ''},
        '22': {msg: '', msg_status: '', msg_error: ''},
    },
    '15': {
        '21': {msg: '', msg_status: '', msg_error: ''},
        '23': {msg: '', msg_status: '', msg_error: ''},
    },
    '18': {
        '24': {msg: '', msg_status: '', msg_error: ''},
        '20': {msg: '', msg_status: '', msg_error: ''},
    }
}
```

For the first option something like the following would be used:

```
let new_list = {};

let temp_id = '20';
let real_id = '111';
let client_id = '18';

for (let key in messages) {
  if (key !== client_id) {
    new_list[key] = messages[key]
    continue;
  }

  for (let mkey in messages[key]) {
    if (mkey === temp_id) {
      new_list[key] = {};
      new_list[key][real_id] = messages[key][temp_id];
      continue;
    }
      new_list[key][mkey] = messages[key][mkey]
  }
  
}
```

For the second option something like the following would be used:

```
function createMessage(message, status, error, id) {
  return {
    msg_id: id,
    msg: message,
    msg_status: status,
    msg_error: error,
  }
}

const new_messages = [createMessage("Hey", "", "", 12), createMessage("Hey", "", "", 18), createMessage("Hey", "", "", 12)]
const userWithMessages = new_messages.filter(message => message.msg_id === 18)
```